# CollectionProperty inside another PropertyGroup

Tags: python

I'm trying to initialize a PropertyGroup with pointers to objects inside another PropertyGroup. I'm getting an error: `bpy_struct "ListItem" registration error: object_group could not register`. Am I doing something wrong? In principle I'm trying to hold pointers to objects in a list, with each list with a label.
Answer from here doesn't seem to be working:[Register Object inside of Another Object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23739/register-object-inside-of-another-object)

```
class ObjectPointer(PropertyGroup):

    obj: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Object)

class ListItem(PropertyGroup):

    name: StringProperty(
        name = "Name"
    )

    object_group: CollectionProperty(type = objectPointer)
```

Inside register():

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_list = CollectionProperty(type = ListItem)
```

Comment: Is your question about how to display a custom name per object? What's the goal? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box/30446#30446 also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159353/31447

Comment: Make sure you register `ObjectPointer` first, then `ListItem` and finally assign it to `my_list` in the register function. Also make sure `(type = objectPointer)` is written like `(type = ObjectPointer)` (ObjectPointer with capital O, but might be just a typo in your question).

Answer (score 3):

Here is all you need to do:

```
class ObjectPointer(PropertyGroup):

    obj: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = bpy.types.Object)

class ListItem(PropertyGroup):

    name: StringProperty(
        name = "Name"
    )

    object_group: CollectionProperty(type = ObjectPointer)
```

Inside `register()` - here are changes:

```
bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectPointer) #firstly register collection property type
bpy.utils.register_class(ListItem) #the one where you use ObjectPointer after
bpy.types.Scene.my_list = CollectionProperty(type = ListItem) #lastly assign
```